# Commiting and get specific revision

Tags: commit, revision, sharpsvn

I work with sharpSVN,i need 2 things:
1) I need to get a revision with specific logmessage
2) When I commit my revision, I want to show every file, that is commiting. I find an event commiting, but I don't know how it works(Commiting and get specific revision)

Comment: And how can I update my work dir with spec revision

Answer (score 1):

Subversion doesn't have a builtin search capability on log messages, so you need to walk through all revisions to find your answer.

(You can call SvnClient.Log() on the path. On the args object set .Retrieve* to false for everything you don't need and put only svn:log in RetrieveProperties for optimal performance. Nothing beats a local cache though)